# OCR functionality and image segmentation in Google Cloud Vision API

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, image-segmentation, google-cloud-vision

I am exploring Google Cloud Vision API for a project which involves Optical Character Recognition (OCR). My project requires not only the extraction of text from images but also the segmentation of these images into individual words or characters.

I've gone through the documentation but I need clarification on the following points:

- Can Google Cloud Vision API segment an image into individual words or characters and return the coordinates of each segment?
- If so, can it also return these segments as individual images?
- If not, what would be the best approach to achieve this using Google Cloud services?

I would appreciate any guidance or resources you could provide to help me understand the capabilities of Google Cloud Vision API with respect to my project requirements.

Comment: Hi @Vaibhac Jain, I have provided an answer, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Cloud Vision  can detect and extract text from images. You  can use vision api for image labeling, face and landmark detection, optical character recognition (OCR), and tagging of explicit content.

You can use cloud vision  advanced text recognition [DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/Feature#type) feature to extract the words,characters and its corresponding coordinates.The response of this feature  is optimized for dense text and documents. When you send an image it will recognise words,characters,segments and its coordinates.For more information you can refer to these links [link1](https://blog.searce.com/tips-tricks-for-using-google-vision-api-for-text-detection-2d6d1e0c6361) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr).

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud's Enterprise Document OCR product offfers [symbol-level](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/process-documents-ocr#symbol_detection) text detection